# How do I use a function inside a loop inside a .then?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I have an Angularjs project that uses Restangular to access the database. I have three layers of data (say mydata, mysubdata, mysubsubdata) and there is a one-to-many relationship between each layer. My problem is that, for my display, I need to concatenate the mysubsubdata to the mysubdata. When I try to get data back from the database, I am hitting a complaint in the compiler that says I can't have a function in a loop. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
DataService.one(mydata.id).getList('mysubdata')
.then(function(data) {
   var dataList = data;
   for (returnedData in dataList) {
     DataService.one(mydata.id).one('mysubdata',returnedData.id).getList('mysubsubdata')
    .then(returnedSubData) {
       dataList = angular.extend(dataList, returnedSubData);
    });
  }
});
```

All the examples I've found have loops inside the .then function or are trying to get a bunch of promises back first. I don't think those apply. I'm still pretty new to Angular, so I may be flailing a bit. Not sure about the extend either, but that's likely a separate question.

Edit: I suspect this should be done with a $q.all but haven't grasped the method yet.

Comment: From my understanding, you need to return a `promise` to use `then`

Comment: To clarify, DataService is using Restangular and is doing that. The first part (up to the second DataService) works okay. Sorry for not explaining that.

Comment: Did you try to make a closure inside cycle?

Comment: @AlexeyAvdeev not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `then()` method inside your loop won't work because of the simple reason that loop does not wait for the promises to be resolved. You can achieve this using recursive method.

```
var myCustomData = null,
    dataList = null,
    dataListCounter = 0;

DataService.one(mydata.id).getList('mysubdata')
  .then(function (data){
     dataList = data;
     myCustomData = mydata;
     $scope.getSubSubData();
});

$scope.getSubSubData = function () {
   if (dataList.length >= dataListCounter)
     return;
   DataService.one(myCustomData.id).one('mysubdata',dataList[dataListCounter].id).getList('mysubsubdata')
     .then(function (returnedSubData) {
        dataList = angular.extend(dataList, returnedSubData);
        dataListCounter++;
        $scope.getSubSubData();
   });
};
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: I seem to have introduced an error in my DataService call, so I am fixing that. I'm trying your answer. Note, I did have to add braces to the if.

Comment: This isn't working yet. It seems that the getSubSubData piece is not getting called. When I step through it, it looks like the getSubSubData line is hit, but the breakpoint inside the function is never hit. Note that this code is inside a service rather than a controller.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Can't do a fiddle, but figured out my issues. You got me 90% of the way there. It turned out a few minor changes were needed. For space reasons, I will put the updated code in an answer, but mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Minor corrections to @Anadi Sharma's response.

```
$scope.getSubSubData = function () {
   if (dataList.length == dataListCounter)
     return;
   DataService.one(myCustomData.id).one('mysubdata',dataList[dataListCounter].id).getList('mysubsubdata')
     .then(function (returnedSubData) {
        dataList[dataListCounter].mysubsubdata = returnedSubData;
        dataListCounter++;
        $scope.getSubSubData();
   });
};
```

Note that I then use a filter when I display the data to concatenate the subsubdata values.